# Taking an Instance of A Time Variable When A Condition Is Met

Tags: java

I am looking for a way to take an instance of a time variable when the else of an if is called as in the situation below, so then I can pass this time taken into another method.

```
double time = getRunningTime();
...
if (..){

}
else{
  *TAKE AN INSTANCE OF VARIABLE TIME AT THIS POINT TO PASS TO ANOTHER
                           METHOD*
}
```

However, if I now pass this into another method by

```
else{
  methodToCall(time)
}
```

Then use this in the other method i.e

```
methodToCall(double time){
   double timeMinusRunningTimeOfIfInPreviousMethod = getRunningTime() - time
   ....
}
```

the variable time will still be changing, however I want it to stay constant.

Thanks, Jack

Comment: What do you mean by **Taking an instance of a time variable**?

Comment: @Keerthivasan By that I mean as soon as the else is called.  take the value of variable time at that every point which will not change, so that that variable can be passed onto another method.

Comment: `theMethodYouWantToCall(time)` ?

Comment: @RC Precisely. If i do that now the variable will still constantly change.

Comment: what do you mean by change? What change, where?

Comment: @RC I will update the question to try and provide clarification

Comment: The value `time` will not change unless you change it in code. I mean that you reassign it with a different value or calling the `getRunningTime()`

Answer (score 0):

From your comment,

> Precisely. If i do that now the variable will still constantly change.

No, `time` will not change if you do that now. In fact, `time` never changes after the first line in your snippet. `time` is a value type of `double`. It does not hold a reference to some constantly changing object.

So what is constantly changing here? Presumably, the return value of `getRunningTime`. When you call the method at a different time, a different value will be returned. Judging from the name, I guess it returns how long has the program been running since some point in time.

Therefore, you probably want to do something like this instead:

```
someMethod(getRunningTime());
```

Or if `getRunningTime` returns the current time and you want to measure how long the if statement took to execute, you can do:

```
someMethod(getRunningTime() - time).
```